# MVC 3 application on local IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, nullreferenceexception

I've had some interesting times deploying a MVC3 app to a localhost IIS server but this one cuts the cake. I am getting a null reference exception when hitting the site from a browser. To be clear, this application works on Cassini, IIS Express and IIS 7 (Win2008) but doesn't work on IIS7.5 (Windows7).

The weird thing is, is that when I attach VS2010 to w3worker process the site WORKS! How weird is that. Once I close out of VS2010 it stops working.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Here is the error:

> ```
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> ```
>
> object.]
>          NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
>   +84
>          DynamicInjector2efc601a855d4eb08717697546358942(Object[]
>   ) +40
>          Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext
>   context) +335
>          Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
>   +177
>          Ninject.KernelBase.b_*9(IContext
>   context) +8
>          System.Linq.<>c*_DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource
>   x) +32
>          System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   +151
>          System.Linq.d__b1`1.MoveNext()
>   +92
>          System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1
>   source) +196
>          Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot
>   root, IParameter[] parameters) +151
>          Elvis.MvcApplication.get_Logger() +33
>          Elvis.MvcApplication.Application_Start()
>   +126
>
> ```
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an
> ```
>
> instance of an object.]
>          System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9028953
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers) +131
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState
>   state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +194
>          System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +339
>          System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +253
>
> ```
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an
> ```
>
> instance of an object.]
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +8950644
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +97
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +256

Answer (score 0):

I think that NLog cannot be run at medium trustlevel, so please confirm that you are running in a full trust environment. More information can be found [here](http://nlog-project.org/forum#nabble-td1685352).

Comment: IIS on the Windows 7 box is set to Full(Internal)